# How can i rewrite my url with get parameters to a cleaner url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Im making a little php web application. And for this application i want to make the url more seo friendly by rewriting the url that contains parameters via htaccess

In this application i have one base index.php where i include the content from the php file from the $_GET['page'] parameter.

for example i would like to have this url:
some-app.com/?page=items&category=1

to this:
some-app.com/items/1

i tried to do make a clean url for pages without parameters

like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?page=$1
```

but when i try it for the pages with parameters like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^items/([0-9]+)$ items&category=$1
```

it does nothing or i get an internal server error

I would like to hear if this is possible or maybe you could suggest an alternative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AltoRouter](http://altorouter.com/) is really useful for doing exactly that, it's a really simple Router Class written in PHP (PHP 5.3+).

Using AltoRouter makes it easier than using Htaccess, as it's easier to add new routes and provides cleaner URLs.

**inndex.php**

```
<?php 

require("AltoRouter.php");

$router = new AltoRouter();

/* Routes */
/* $router->map(Method, Route , Target , Name) */

/* Home page */
$router->map('GET','/', 'home.php', 'home');

/* Single item page */
$router->map('GET','/item/[*:id ]', 'item.php', 'item');

/* View category */
$router->map('GET','/category/[*:id]', 'category.php', 'category');


/* Match route */
$match = $router->match();

/* Check if there is a match */
if($match) {
  header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
  require $match['target'];
} else {
  header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
  echo "Error 404";
}

?>
```

For items, your URL can be `https://example.com/item/%ID%` with `%ID%` being the item's ID.
**item.php**

```
<?php

/* Get item ID from URL */
$itemId = $match["params"]["id"];

/* Continue to rest of your script, and you can use $ItemID to get item data */

?>
```

For category, your URL can be `https://example.com/category/%ID%`
**category.php**

```
<?php

/* Get category ID from URL */
$categoryId = $match["params"]["id"];

/* Continue to rest of your script, and you can use $category to show all items in category */

?>
```

You'll also need to add the following lines into your .htaccess file. This rewrites all requests to your index.php file, which is exactly what you need for AltoRouter to work.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

All of the files need to be in the main directory of your web server, typically known as `public_html`. You can place both `item.php` & `category.php` in another folder, but you will need to change the Target in map, for example:

```
$router->map('GET','/item/[*:id ]', 'views/item.php', 'item');
```

Comment: This is exactly what i needed. Thank you very much!!